# flutter Compare complex 2 List<Object>

Tags: flutter, compare

I'm still new to flutter, I need your help.
I get the data from a json file that has a nested class structure.
Example:

```
[
{
"name" : User 1
"phone": [
"+793476522"
"9988456733222"
"45-44"
],
" age": 45
"email address": user1@ya.ru ,
"address": {
[5 Lenin Street, Moscow],
[1, 5, 45]
}
"work" : {
[Moscow, Mira Street, 34],
["+793476522", "45-44"]
},
" name" : User 2
////////////////
]
```

The User, Phone, Address, serialization and deserialization classes are implemented. All data is loaded into the TextField. The user changes the data and they need to be saved to a similar json file.

When I start the application, I get a List with all the data from the file.

```
 final List<User> listuser = [];
Future<void> readJson() async {
    final String response = await rootBundle.loadString(initialAssetFile);
    final json = jsonDecode(response);
    if (json != null) {
      json.forEach((element) {
        final rls = User.fromJson(element);
        listuser.add(rls);
      });
    }
  }
```

I make a copy, with which I then want to compare the modified listuser

```
final List<User> oldlistuser =
            listuser.map((e) => User.from(e)).toList();
```

Next on the onchange of each Textfield I change the listuser. Then I try to compare oldlist user and listuser and here I encounter a problem.

```
onPressed: () {
if (!DeepCollectionEquality().equal(oldlistuser, listuser)) {
showDialog(
///////
}
}
```

No deep comparison of oldlistuser and listuser, only parameters like "name", "age" are compared. Changes to "address" are not compared.
For all classes tried to override the operator

```
@override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Address &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          other.home == home &&
          other.street == street &&
          other.city == city;
int get hashCode => home.hashCode ^ street.hashCode ^ city.hashCode;
```

How to compare two List with nested classes?
Thanks and sorry for my english
Update:
The class I'm trying to compare is something like this

```
class User {
  List<Address> address;
  int age;
String email;
List<Phone> phone;
/////
}
class Address {
List<dynamic> housepos;
List<dynamic> apartment;
}
class Phone {
String number1;
String number2;
String number3;
}
```

I get a new value, send it to the variable user = User{}, send user to listuser. Then I try to compare List listuser и oldlistuser.

Comment: It might be easiest to just compare their `toJson()` with each other

Comment: Please provide the code of the class you are comparing. It may help with figuring out the source of issue.
Also, it may be better to make JSON a little bit more readable with comfortable indents

Comment: @Ivo, toJson() returns dynamic, how to compare nested classes?

Comment: @RelaxedSoul, Json is used in another project, I can't change its structure. I edited the first post with an example class structure. thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the "address" field in your json response is a json object with some arrays just laying around. I think that could cause problems while deserialising it, which may then cause issues with your other logic since there is no valid data present in those fields in your data classes;

It could have been:

```
"address":{
"residential":[5, Lenin Street, Moscow]
}
```

Instead of:

```
"address": {
[5 Lenin Street, Moscow],
[1, 5, 45]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've dealt with deserialization, all the values I get. I cannot edit the structure, it is used in other projects.